# Groovy way to dynamically invoke a static method

Tags: groovy

I know in Groovy you can invoke a method on a class/object using a string.  For example:

```
Foo."get"(1)
  /* or */
String meth = "get"
Foo."$meth"(1)
```

Is there a way to do this with the class?  I have the name of the class as a string and would like to be able to dynamically invoke that class.  For example, looking to do something like:

```
String clazz = "Foo"
"$clazz".get(1)
```

I think I'm missing something really obvious, just am not able to figure it out.

Comment: classes dont get "invoked" - only methods. What is it exactly that you want to invoke? do you want to do something like MyOwnClass.static_property()? or myInstanceOfClass.methodName()?

Comment: My guess is that he wants to invoke a static method on a class.

Comment: I want to invoke a static method on a class, a class I that I don't know until run time.  I know the Java way is to use Class.forName, was just curious if there was a Groovy way to do this like their is for methods.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
def cl = Class.forName("org.package.Foo")
cl.get(1)
```

A little bit longer but should work.

If you want to create "switch"-like code for static methods, I suggest to instantiate the classes (even if they have only static methods) and save the instances in a map. You can then use

```
map[name].get(1)
```

to select one of them.

**[EDIT]** `"$name"` is a `GString` and as such a valid statement. `"$name".foo()` means "call the method `foo()` of the class `GString`.

**[EDIT2]** When using a web container (like Grails), you have to specify the classloader. There are two options:

```
Class.forName("com.acme.MyClass", true, Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
```

or

```
Class.forName("com.acme.MyClass", true, getClass().classLoader)
```

The first option will work only in a web context, the second approach also works for unit tests. It depends on the fact that you can usually use the same classloader as the class which invokes `forName()`.

If you have problems, then use the first option and set the `contextClassLoader` in your unit test:

```
def orig = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
try {
    Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = getClass().classLoader

    ... test ...
} finally {
    Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = orig
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to find out if there was a "Groovy" way of doing Class.forName, similar to how they made reflection on methods so easy.  I do appreciate your answer and suspect that this might be the only way.

Comment: @John: No, that's not possible. I asked on the Groovy ML. You have to call Class.forName() because "$name" is a GString and Groovy doesn't try to be smart about the contents of the variable "name".

Comment: @Aaron - thanks, I read the thread on the Groovy ML and that just the info I was looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work with classes defined in the current script, does it? class TestName {
}

Class.forName("TestName")

Comment: Sure. Why not? The script is read, compiled and then run. At the time when it is run, all the class files exist, so Class.forName() can find them.

Comment: With Grails domain classes, you will get a ClassNotFoundException unless you manually specify the correct class loader:  `Class.forName("com.acme.MyClass", true, Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)` - thanks for [BinaryBuffer](http://binarybuffer.com/2012/03/grails-class-forname-classnotfoundexception) for the tip.

Comment: @miek: Thanks, I've improved my answer.

Answer (score 31):

As suggested by Guillaume Laforge on Groovy ML,

```
("Foo" as Class).get(i)
```

would give the same result.

I've tested with this code:

```
def name = "java.lang.Integer"
def s = ("$name" as Class).parseInt("10")
println s
```

Comment: The first example ("Foo" as Class).get(i) does not seem to work in grails to dynamically load a domain class.

Comment: This works in grails 1.3.4 
grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(name);

Answer (score 3):

An augmentation to Chanwit's answer illustrating creation of an instance:

```
def dateClass = 'java.util.Date' as Class
def date = dateClass.newInstance()
println date
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

def target = application.domainClasses.find{it.name == 'ClassName'}
target.clazz.invokeMethod("Method",args)
```

With this you don't need to specify the package name. Be careful though if you have the same class name in two different packages.

Comment: I'm running Grails 1.2.1 and Groovy 1.6.3, and I was getting class not found exceptions using the ClassForName() and as Class casting methods above. This particular approach worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Melix on Groovy ML pointed me in the "right" direction on dynamic class method invokation awhile back, quite useful:

```
// define in script (not object) scope  
def loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader()

// place this in some MetaUtils class, invoked on app startup  
String.metaClass.toClass = {  
    def classPath = getPath(delegate) // your method logic to determine 'path.to.class'
    Class.forName(classPath, true, this.loader)  
}

// then, anywhere in your app  
"Foo".toClass().bar()
```

You could create another string metaClass method to create instances as well, refactoring as appropriate:

```
String.metaClass.toObject = {  
    def classPath = getPath(delegate)  
    Class.forName(classPath, true, this.loader).newInstance()  
}
```

Groovy is pure fun ;--)

Answer (score 1):

I'm running version 1.8.8 groovy... and the simple example works.

```
Import my.Foo
def myFx="myMethodToCall"
def myArg = 12

Foo."$myFx"(myArg)
```

Calls Foo.myMethodToCall(12) as expected and desired. I don't know if this has always been the case though.