# Groovy way to dynamically instantiate a class from String

Tags: groovy

The answers of [this question about the Groovy way to dynamically invoke a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576955/groovy-way-to-dynamically-invoke-a-class) were very helpful but I'm having trouble with the following case:

I defined a simple Groovy class:

```
class Item {
  def id = 1
  def data = [ "a", "b" ]
}
```

I then defined a simple utility class that wants to dynamically load the Item class:

```
class Util {
  static def main(args) {
     def cls = "Item" as Class
     def instance = cls.newInstance()
     println instance.toString()
  }
}
```

Util.groovy is in the same folder as Item.groovy

When I try to run Util.groovy I get the following error:

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: 
Cannot cast object 'Item' with class 'java.lang.String' 
to class 'java.lang.Class' due to: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Item
        at Util.main(Util.groovy:3)
```

The only way that I could make it work was by using groovyc to precompile Item.groovy, but this misses the point of being Groovy :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This works, using the [underlying `GroovyClassLoader`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)):

```
def instance = this.class.classLoader.loadClass( 'Item', true, false )?.newInstance()
```

Comment: You should probably change `this.class` to `this.getClass()`.  It's generally recommended to use the full method to avoid [property or map lookups (or invokeMethod overrides)](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/class-vs-getClass-td368617.html).

Comment: Why bother when we know this isn't a map? Embrace the dynamic! ;-)

Comment: You can also supply constructor arguments straight into newInstance() in 3 different forms: map, array, or comma list

Answer (score 7):

I just had to do this and found an interesting way--so I thought I'd come back and mention it.

I had A problem with this because I wanted to pass a value to newInstance (use a non-default constructor) and all the solutions seemed to be a little bit of work (I'm lazy, okay?)

Anyway, suppose you want to create a new Integer(5)... try this:

```
c = "java.lang.Integer"
p = "5"
def result = Eval.me("return new ${c}(${p})")
assert(result == 5)
```

Worked really well although I'm sure it's about the slowest solution possible.  Has the advantage that the method is applicable to many other situations.

Comment: IT SEEMS javascript plagia :)

Comment: @Bill Interesting at intellectual level, but this is really not in groovy way, like  Abdennour TOUMI said

Comment: I agree, just mentioned it for completeness and ease--sometimes you're just writing a one-off script and this is easy to remember and flexible.

Comment: eval() is a bad practice in every language, it's slow and a security harm if the things evaluated could be controlled by a user

Answer (score 0):

Another option using Class.forName() from Java (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

Example working code in Groovy:

```
class Dog {

   def bark()
   {
      println 'woof'
   }
}


def name = 'Dog'

def ins = Class.forName(name).newInstance()

ins.bark() // woof
```