# Gradle equivalent for Class.forName

Tags: gradle

Is there a gradle equivalent for Class.forName or a more gradle/groovy way of doing it.

What I am trying to achieve in gradle is the following:

```
    for(String name : new String[]{
            MyImpl1.class.getName() ,
            MyImpl2.class.getName() ,
            MyImpl3.class.getName()}) {
        MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface)Class.forName(name).newInstance();
        myInterface.configure();
    }
```

Where MyImpl1, MyImpl2 and MyImpl3 implements MyInterface

Answer (score 0):

As per [Guillaume LaForge's](http://glaforge.appspot.com/) (one of the main contributors to the Groovy language) [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409387/4428370):

```
def name = "java.lang.Integer"// Fully qualified class name
def s = ("$name" as Class).parseInt("10")
println s
```

But I guess if you want greater control over the specific classloader, doing it the Java way `Class.forName("Foo", true, this.getClass().getClassLoader())` works in Groovy too.